# ggsurvplot: Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE)

Tags: r, survival

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4,1), event=c(1,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to create a survival curve

```
library(survival)
km <- survfit(Surv(time,event) ~ 1, data = df)

library("survminer")

ggsurvplot(km,  color = "#2E9FDF",
                    data =df,
           ncensor.plot = TRUE)
```

That's ok, but get warning

```
Warning message:
Now, to change color palette, use the argument palette= '#2E9FDF' instead of color = '#2E9FDF'
```

I change

```
ggsurvplot(km,  palette = "#2E9FDF",
                    data =df,
           ncensor.plot = TRUE)
```

And we have error

```
Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name "strata"
```

The problem is in `ncensor.plot`. When we remove it no error

```
ggsurvplot(km,  palette = "#2E9FDF",
                        data =df)
```

how to fix `Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE)`

Comment: Looks like a bug in the code. It doesn't work when you have only one strata (you have a constant `~1`). You might consider filing a [github issue](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues) with the package author (or just ignoring the warning you get when you use `color=`)

Comment: Actually never mind, there already seems to be an issue for exactly this case: https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/298